# How to install certain packages before building wheels for other packages in requirements.txt using pip?

Tags: python, build, pip, google-cloud-build, requirements.txt

Here is a section of my `requirements.txt` file.

```
pystan
cython
lunardate
holidays
convertdate
plotly
fbprophet
```

While using pip install, all the packages are downloaded, built and installed in the **same order** as expected.

However, for building the *wheel* of `fbprophet`, it needs `pystan` as a dependency. And since `pystan` is in a ***"built"*** stage then and ***not yet installed***, the `fbprophet` install always fails.

On using pip on the above requirements.txt I get this log:

```sh
Collecting pystan (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/ea/c004537cd92c7dcc0112756d2cbc99707e3f67966e57285cdaca68b2e364/pystan-2.19.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (67.2MB)
Saved /tmp/tmpKl0DOi/wheel/pystan-2.19.0.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting cython (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/d3/03a01bcf424eb86d3e9d818e2082ced2d512001af89183fca6f550c32bc2/Cython-0.29.13-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1MB)
Saved /tmp/tmpKl0DOi/wheel/Cython-0.29.13-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting lunardate (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/7e/377a3cbba646ec0cf79433ef858881d809a3b87eb887b0901cb83c66a758/lunardate-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Saved /tmp/tmpKl0DOi/wheel/lunardate-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting holidays (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/17/a452275a0b3e811a381137ff6a61649086af4c5bf2a25755f518cc64b39e/holidays-0.9.11.tar.gz (81kB)
Collecting convertdate (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/83/d0fa07078f4d4ae473a89d7d521aafc66d82641ea0af0ef04a47052e8f17/convertdate-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Saved /tmp/tmpKl0DOi/wheel/convertdate-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting plotly (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/2b/4ca10995bfbdefd65c4238f9a2d3fde33705d18dd50914dd13302ec1daf1/plotly-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.1MB)
Saved /tmp/tmpKl0DOi/wheel/plotly-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting fbprophet (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/fb/ad98d46773929079657706e6b2b6e366ba6c282bc2397d8f9b0ea8e5614c/fbprophet-0.5.tar.gz (49kB)
Skipping pystan, due to already being wheel.
Skipping cython, due to already being wheel.
Skipping lunardate, due to already being wheel.
Skipping convertdate, due to already being wheel.
Skipping plotly, due to already being wheel.
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): started
Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command /env/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-wheel-0mthcx8p/fbprophet/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-gp8dl1oz:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/fbprophet
creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-wheel-0mthcx8p/fbprophet/setup.py", line 120, in <module>
"""
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/pip-wheel-0mthcx8p/fbprophet/setup.py", line 44, in run
build_stan_model(target_dir)
File "/tmp/pip-wheel-0mthcx8p/fbprophet/setup.py", line 27, in build_stan_model
from pystan import StanModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to install everything in one go. Split `requirements.txt` into two phases — first, install `pystan` (and perhaps `cython`), then install `fbprophet`.

Comment: Or run the command `pip install pystan` before installing the `requirements.txt` file

Comment: I am trying to build a Google App Engine. In the standard environment, I can only provide this `requirements.txt` file and it handles the rest of it. Cannot really write commands (would need a flexible aka. paid environment for that). So I really want to figure out if there is a way to do it for standard runtimes in GAE

Comment: @SayanSil were you able to figure this out? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message when I ran what you had above, but was able to `pip install -r requirements.txt` with this as my `requirements.txt`:

```
pystan==2.19.1.1
cython
lunardate
holidays
convertdate
plotly
fbprophet
```

pip was likely using an unsupported version of `pystan`. According to [the fbprophet installation documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html), as of January 20th 2022 (when I am writing this), '`fbprophet` currently does not support `pystan`>=3.0.'